# Where is the best place to put an exception in a Python nested loop, code fails at a large scale? - Retokenize API mid loop in Exception

Tags: python, api, nested-loops

I have built this API pull and it works well but when trying to pull a larger dataset it fails.  Larger = more artist IDs.  The traceback error is shown below.  I am guessing that either the api times out and the refresh isnt working or there is no data point for the date.  Either way I want the loop to continue.

Here is the other functions that go into the functions in the exception clause:

After further discussion I am trying to retokenize the API mid loop in the exception clause.

```
def get_token_response():
     headers = {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     }

     data = '{"refreshtoken":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}'

     response = requests.post('https://api.chartmetric.com/api/token', headers=headers, data=data)
     
     return response

def get_token():
     response = get_token_response()
     response_json = json.loads(response.content)
     token = response_json['token']
     return token

def build_headers(token):
     from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

     headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
     headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
     headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer {}".format(token)
     
     return headers
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\BRETT~1.ZAZ\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16572/1768635037.py", line 22, in <module>
    token = get_token()

  File "C:\Users\BRETT~1.ZAZ\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16572/1345341042.py", line 33, in get_token
    response_json = json.loads(response.content)

  File "C:\Users\brett.zaziski\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "C:\Users\brett.zaziski\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "C:\Users\brett.zaziski\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

Here is the code:

```
for artist, s, u in zip(artist_ids,Since, Until):
    try:
        for stat, field in zip(stats, fields):
            url_stat = 'https://api.chartmetric.com/api/artist/{}/stat/{}?field={}&since={}&until={}'.format(artist, stat, field, s,u)
            resp_stat = requests.get(url_stat, headers=headers)
            resp_json_stat = json.loads(resp_stat.text)
            response_list = resp_json_stat['obj']
            response_list.pop('link')
            for k in response_list.keys():
                the_array = response_list[k]
                for a_dict in the_array:
                    a_dict['artist'] = artist
                    a_dict['domain'] = stat
                    a_dict['field'] = field
                df = pd.DataFrame(the_array)
                df_fan_metrics.append(df)
                final_df = pd.concat(df_fan_metrics)
    except Exception:
           missing.append(str(artist) +"_" + stat+"_" +field)
           token = get_token()
           headers = build_headers(token)
    continue
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: You've given us code that doesn't match the exception...

Comment: Can you elaborate? would it be except "Other Error"?  or something like that?

Comment: The second line of the exception is `response_json = json.loads(response.content)`. That line doesn't appear in the code you posted. Therefore, the code does not match the exception. As in the exception is from a different place than the code you posted.

Comment: Thank you, for your input.  I updated the question, you are right, the error is in the exception function.  Is there a reason it wont retokenize in the exception clause?

Comment: Are you asking how to continue the loop on exception, how to fix the exception, or how to recalculate the token+header on an exception? All three are mentioned on this page.

Comment: @vahlala I believe the error is coming from the functions within the exception so I guess I am asking how to recalculate the token+header on an exception.

Comment: It looks like get_token is returning an empty JSON object, so you need to work out why that is happening, otherwise the situation doesn't look recoverable.

Comment: That's a lot of code (that can raise a lot of different exceptions) in a single `try` statement. It's a bit of a stretch to assume that any exception that block can possibly raise will be adequately handled using the same three lines of code.

Comment: Catch *specific* exceptions that you know how to handle, and put only the code that might raise those specific exceptions in the `try` block.

Comment: @chepner I want to have it refresh the token when it fails so it needs to be in the except block

Comment: The only reason to refresh the token would be if `requests.get` fails. No other exception that code might raise indicates a need to do so.